# Error triying to downland remote files with Papaparse

Tags: javascript, vue.js, papaparse

I have started some days ago using Papaparse library and I have an error which i don´t know how can i solve it.
I am triying to downland a remote file, i have written the next code:

```
 downlandCSV:function(){
            Papa.parse("https://github.com/../some.csv",{
                downland:true,
                complete:function(results){
                    console.log(results);
                }
            })
```

In the terminal i see this:

```
{data: Array(1), errors: Array(1), meta: {…}}
data: Array(1)
0: ["https://github.com/../some.csv"]
```

So the data array has one element and it is the url which i have introduced.
If anyone knows how can i correct this please tell me.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us the actual errors?

Comment: {data: Array(1), errors: Array(1), meta: {…}}
data: Array(1)
0: ["https://github.com/.../some.csv"]
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
errors: [{…}]
meta: {delimiter: ",", linebreak: "\n", aborted: false, truncated: false, cursor: 56}

Comment: Could you `console.log(JSON.stringify(results))` instead and show us what is output? Feel free to edit your question and add these extra details.

Comment: This is what i have obtained. --> {"data":[["https://github.com/some.csv"]],"errors":[{"type":"Delimiter","code":"UndetectableDelimiter","message":"Unable to auto-detect delimiting character; defaulted to ','"}],"meta":{"delimiter":",","linebreak":"\n","aborted":false,"truncated":false,"cursor":56}}

Comment: I think that the problem is when i try to read .csv from github, i dont know why it is taking the url as the data